# Tests of homogeneity of proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, heteroscedasticity

Suppose that we have $m$ samples $(X_{i1}, X_{i2},\cdots, X_{in})$, the samples are independent ,and I want to test the proportions of each sample, let's take this example: the samples represent people from different ages ($[10,20[,[20;30[,\cdots)$, and the responses are "yes" or "no", "smoker" or "non smoker", so $X_{i1}$ have $m$ person of the age $[10,20[$, and every person responds with "yes" or "no" to the question, are you a smoker. The whole data looks like this

```
      X_{i1}   X_{i2} ....... X_{in}
  1      1        0               1
  2      0        1               0
  3      1        1               1
  .      .        .               .
  .      .        .               .
  m      1        0               0
```

We can estimate the proportion of smokers of each sample and we note them $p_{j}$ ($j=1,\cdots,n)$, and suppose that $\sum p_{i} \neq 1$ and that $(X_{i1}, X_{i2},\cdots, X_{in})$ is not distributed as  multinomial. My objective is to test whether the proportion of smokers is the same across all the samples, so the null hypothesis is $H_{0}\!: `` p_{1}=p_{2}=\cdots=p_{n}"$. How can one perform this test?

Comment: I think it would help if you can say something about the way in which the sample is *not* multinomially distributed. What is the nature of the violation, is it the independence assumption for instance?

Comment: @Silverfish, yes it's the independence assumption.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. Why does assuming independence imply a distribution is not multinomial?

Comment: @gung I'm not assuming that independence imply a distribution is not multinomial, it's just how my data are?

Comment: If your columns represent ages do you not want to fit a model including age? Just testing for heterogeneity is an omnibus test for any departure.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ch-square test work best in this case. Does this help? http://www.pindling.org/Math/Statistics/Textbook/Chapter11_Chi_Square/homogeneity.html

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. We try to avoid [link-only answers](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) which are subject to link-rot and [may be deleted](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). As such this is more of a comment than an answer in its own right. If you're able, could you expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: More specifically, can you explain why the chi-square test is "best in this case?"